# Determine if this statement is true or false

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is this statement true or false?

Statement: Each differential equation on the form $y '= f (y)$ with f having continuous derivative on the entire real axis $ℝ$ leads to that all solutions $y(x)$ defined on the entire $ℝ$.

So if the continuous derivative is defined for all real numbers, is all solutions $y(x)$ defined for all real numbers for $y'=f(y)$

I have tried to solve the equation an example like $y '= y ^ 2$ where the right-hand side has continuous derivatives and makes conclusions itself
but I am not sure what the answer is...

Comment: Identical question with discussion in comments: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3029066/115115

Comment: And yes, add the initial condition $y(0)=1$ to get a soluton $y(x)=1/(1-x)$ that is not defined on all of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Re-posting a question is not the way to draw more attention to it (or to escape down- and close-votes). If you have context to add, add it to the previous question. This improves the question and can reverse the trend in negative votes.

Comment: Ah ... I see that this isn't merely a re-post of a previous question. You have created a new account for this purpose (distinct from ["Jacob Andreasson"](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/623678/jacob-andreasson)) ... which is an even *less* appropriate way to escape down- and close-votes. This is a violation of community standards.